# Numbering list elements with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string structured like that:

```
BLOCK
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        LIST2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        LIST2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
BLOCK
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        LIST2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            LIST3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        LIST2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

...

and I want it to transform into like that:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Comment: @Michael: Regex.Replace with a custom MatchEvaluator works quite well here.

Comment: @dtb: Sure, unless any of your items contain the words BLOCK, LIST1, etc.  (Yes, you could modify the pattern to account for this).  Why not just use a loop over the lines?  That's effectively what you're doing with a Regex and MatchEvaluator, except a loop is clearer in intent and you can even do some trivial error checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = "BLOCK\r\n    LIST1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...";

var levels = new List<string> { "BLOCK", "LIST1", "LIST2", "LIST3" };
var counter = levels.ToDictionary(level => level, level => 0);

// Replace each key word with incremented counter,
// while resetting deeper levels to 0.
var result = Regex.Replace(input, string.Join("|", levels), m =>
{
    for (int i = levels.IndexOf(m.Value) + 1; i < levels.Count; i++)
    {
        counter[levels[i]] = 0;
    }
    return (++counter[m.Value]).ToString() + ".";
});
```

*Result:*

```
1.
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
2.
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to have seperate counters for every level?

Comment: There's a separate counter for every level in my code (i.e. a dictionary of counters). Is the output not what you're looking for?

Comment: I may need to order some levels alphabetical (e.g. A., B., C., ...). Thats way i'm planing to store characters within a char array and use some level counters to get data from it.

Comment: I believe that my answer answers your question as it is right now. If you have a new question/requirements, please [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).